# How many parallel process can I run?

Tags: parallel-processing, .net-core, task-parallel-library

I have a corei7 processor with 8 logical processors.

I'm trying to run a parallel task in dotnet core 2.2 using parallel.For.
when I measure start time there are 9 tasks started in parallel. 
Isn't it suppose to be just 8?

below you can see :

i => [ThreadId],[ProcessorNumber] == starttime - endtime

[image]

Parallel tasks result

Comment: It looks like you have 10, numbered 0-9.  While your i7 may have 8 processing cores, you can create more threads than this---however, only 8 (or less) of them run at a given instant.  Depending on their configuration (and I'm not sure what all .net supports) they may queue until prior threads complete, or [timeslice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeslicing) core time between them.

Comment: An other things is who decides which processor to be used (in a dotnet app) ? 
is it my operation system (Windows here) or it's determined by my hardware?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run however many tasks in parallel that you want, but the processor only has 8 logical cores to process 8 threads simultaneously. The rest will always queue up and wait their turn.

So if you have 16 parallel processes, which each take 200ms to run, then you will run process 1-8 in parallel for 200ms, then 9-16 in parallel for 200ms, totalling at 400ms. If you had 4 logical cores, you would run process 1-4, 5-8, 9-12, 13-16 in parallel, totalling in at 800ms.